# ActionResult not correctly getting parameter

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

In my Home/Index view I have a list view which displays cards with the photo and details of all uploads each containing an action link on click for each card:

```
@model IEnumerable<FunPetPics.Models.PetPhotoModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

@if (Model == null || !Model.Any())
{
    <p>uploads will be displayed here</p>

}
else
{

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        @await Html.PartialAsync("_PetPhotoModelFilter")
    }

    <div class="card-columns">

        @foreach (var upload in Model)
        {
         

   <a href='@Url.Action( "Rate", "Details", upload.Id )'>

                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="@("~/UploadedPhotos/"+  upload.ImageName)" asp-append-version="true">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">@upload.Title</h4>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">@upload.PetName</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">@upload.DateUploaded</p>
                        <p class="card-text">@upload.Description</p>
                        <p class="card-subtitle">Ratings:</p>
                        <p class="card-text">
                            Cute:@upload.AverageCutenessRating/5<br />
                            Funny:@upload.AverageFunnynessRating/5<br />
                            Awsome:@upload.AverageAwsomnessRating/5<br />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        }
    </div>
```

DetailsControler:

```
using FunPetPics.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Linq;

namespace FunPetPics.Controllers
{
    public class DetailsController : ControllerBase
    {
        public DetailsController(FunPetPicsContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        [HttpGet]
        //[Route("Details/Rate/{id}")] when I add this the controller doesn't work and I get page not found
        public IActionResult Rate(int id)
        {
            var model = _context.PetPhotos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

For now the Details/Rate view is meant to just display the photo until I can get the rest working:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

@model PetPhotoModel


@{
    <img src="@("~/UploadedPhotos/"+  ((PetPhotoModel)Model).ImageName)" asp-append-version="true">
}
```

When the link displayed from the Home/Index page displayed on the browser it takes me to `https://localhost:44316/Rate/Details` (why is there no id?) and the `id` in the controler is 0 (not the correct one).

I have also tried adding this attribute to the controller's `Rate()` method: `[Route("Details/Rate/{id}")]` but no breakpoints are hit in the controller and it displays page not found with the same URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using [`Url.Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_UrlHelper_Action_System_String_System_String_System_Object_) correctly. Leave the `Route` attribute in, and change your view to use this instead, note how it uses an anonymous object to allow MVC to link the `id` value to a matching parameter:

```
@Url.Action( "Rate", "Details", new { id = upload.Id })
```